# How does Gridview.EditIndex = 1 work to edit all rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I was searching how to change mode of gridview row to Edit mode.. And, I got one answer,

```
Gridview1.EditIndex =1;
```

So, I put that into Rowcommand event. I thought it simply change mode of first row regard less pressing Edit button anywhere from any row. But surprisingly, its just changing row mode, where edit button it pressed. Can anyone tell me how does this work?

---

I am clicking Edit button, but it is custom Link Button, which has CommandName="Edit", and then I put this code in my .cs file

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = 2; // tested in VS 2008, .NET 3.5
        // Here doesn't matter, if I write 1,2 or any number, but when I click Edit button from  row, then same row only go into Edit mode.
    }
   ------
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to put your GridView in Edit mode programmatically,set the `EditIndex` property to the appropriate row.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = 1;
}
```

**NOTE:**

1.) In case you are binding gridview from markup, using DataSourceControls such as `SqlDataSource`, No Need to call the `GridView.Bind()`.

2.) If you are binding GridView at runtime using the DataSource property, you should rebind your gridView.

In **your Question**: `surprisingly, its just changing row mode, where edit button is pressed.`, since you are clicking the `Edit` button, handle the `OnRowEditing` event and set the `NewEditIndex` property, if you want some other row to be in edit mode::

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGrIdView" 
     OnRowEditing="CustomersGridView_Editing" 
     OnRowCommand="CustomersGridView_RowCommand"
     .... />

 protected void CustomersGridView_Editing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
      e.NewEditIndex = 3; // Tested in VS 2010, Framework 4   
    }
```

***Now regardless of any row's `Edit` button clicked, you will always find, the 3rd row in Edit mode.*** [ Row Numbering starts from 0 ]

This is what [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx) has to say about `EditIndex` property. **Most of the time, we use the Option C**.

This property is typically used only in the following scenarios, which involve handlers for specific events:

```
a. You want the GridView control to open in edit mode for a specific row
   the first time that the page is displayed. To do this, you can set the 
   EditIndex property in the handler for the Load event of the Page class
   or of the GridView control.

b. You want to know which row was edited after the row was updated. 
   To do this, you can retrieve the row index from the EditIndex property
   in the RowUpdated event handler.

c. You are binding the GridView control to a data source by setting the 
   DataSource property programmatically. In this case you must set the 
   EditIndex property in the RowEditing and RowCancelingEdit event handlers.
```

Comment: I want to know how it is happening rather than How can I edit same row, regardless pressing edit button anywhere.

Comment: I guess, except the middle section of the answer, the top and Last section has explanation as to how it happens.